# Tor Browser Bundle 3.5. on macosx 10.8 can't connect to other websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, mac

Browser looks like it's connected to Tor, (I see Tor congratulations page and green onion Tor enabled button) but cannot connect to any websites ( its always "connecting" in browser tab then times out with problems loading page error).I've tried changing identity.

I have no problems loading websites like chrome or Safari when connected to net not using Tor.

message log:

```
08/01/2014 01:41:45.340 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. 
08/01/2014 01:41:45.475 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit. 
08/01/2014 01:41:45.754 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
08/01/2014 01:41:45.754 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done. 
08/01/2014 01:41:46.606 [NOTICE] New control connection opened. 
08/01/2014 01:43:44.322 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for socks info) 
08/01/2014 01:45:13.321 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for socks info) 
08/01/2014 01:46:44.322 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for socks info) 
08/01/2014 01:47:46.322 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for socks info)
```

any fix suggestion gratefully accepted.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1273/71

Comment: I'm assuming you are otherwise connected to the internet (obvious question I know). So maybe you have a firewall on your router or a software firewall running on the Mac ? It may well need configuring to work with Tor. I managed to stop Tor working once for a while by playing with PFfirewall.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using Sophos by any chance?

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10521

Comment: Welcome to Tor.SE! It would be great if you could expand this, perhaps with a short summary of the bug you've linked to. You could also add things like how to check if Sophos is running, and how to change the Sophos settings to solve this problem. (I know that those steps are in the bug report, but a good answer should be able to stand on its own without any of the links - incase the links stop working in the future).